# Mediastore scan does not notice mp3 album artwork tagging

Tags: android, android-layout

My code behavior changes at the artwork for a single MP3 file. By opening the MP3 file on my PC the artwork got changed but by opening the MP3 file on the android device nothing happens. The shown artwork is still the old one.

I tried this:

```
Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
File f = new File(song_path);
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
FindCoverActivity.this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

but nothing happend.

I tried another thing: By changing the artwork AND the name of the album the mediastore immediatly noticed what was going on and by opening the mp3 file on the android phone again, the artwork gets displayed correctly with the new artwork. But it is not my goal to change important mp3 tags like the album name. Could this be a bug or has anyone suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method instead of `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` and see if you have better results.

Also, make sure that the file's last-modified timestamp is changed when you save your modified artwork. I'm not an expert at such MP3 file modifications, but if there is a timestamp tag in there, you might consider updating that timestamp as well. Basically, you need to make sure that the `MediaStore` realizes that there is a change that requires an update of its metadata.

If all else fails, you could try to work out an approach that *temporarily* modifies the album name in a minor fashion (e.g., appends a space), then changes it back. This is a hack, but it may be your only reliable option.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot. My solution: I used the lib jaudiotagger for tagging the audio files. This was false because it does not tell the Mediastore about modifications!